# jsLint shows "somefunction() was used before it was defined" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, error-handling, jslint

I am new to jQuery and I am using jsLint on jsFiddle to test if I have errors on my code snippets. Below is the structure of the code I am using but jsLint shows that my function `expandToggle()` was used before it was defined:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        expandToggle();  
});

function expandToggle() {
        //dosomething
}
```

Can someone help me what this error means?

Comment: It means that the function is called before it was defined.... from a *lexical* perspective (not sure if this is the right expression)(we all know that `expandToggle` will be available). If you move the function declaration to the top, it should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means what it says. To make jsLint calm down switch your code around.

```
function expandToggle() {
        //dosomething
}

$(document).ready(function() {
        expandToggle();  
});
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I just tried. I thought the problem was trickier than that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It means this:

> $(document).ready(function() {
>           **expandToggle();**   });

Was before this:

> function expandToggle() {
>           //dosomething }

To fix just rearrange them:

> function expandToggle() {
>           //dosomething }
>
> $(document).ready(function() {
>           expandToggle();   });

Answer (score 1):

as the error states , define the function first

```
function expandToggle() {
        //dosomething
}
```

then use it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        expandToggle();  
});
```